# Rails - Remote Image Upload not working ONLY on Mobile Devices

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ajax, mobile, file-upload

I have a Rails 4.2.8 (Ruby 2.5.1) app using Carrierwave and Remotipart to upload images via Ajax (with `remote: true`. Everything works great on desktop or tablet, but when I try and upload an image from a mobile device (either in production or using ngrok to tunnel my local version) the remote form never actually submits.

Basically what happens is the filename quickly disappears from beside the 'Choose File' input button and it instead says 'no file selected', the button gets immediately disabled (due to the `data: disable_with:` attribute) and stays that way forever. And the `Post` request never gets run/never hits my server.

I've tested only on an IOS device so far and that's where it fails. I also tested with the mobile layout from Chrome's Dev tools on my Macbook and it works fine from there. Otherwise, on the IOS device, it is happening in both Chrome and Safari.

The fact that the Post request never actually touches my server is mystifying me. I found this issue about Rails https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17947 throwing errors when an empty file form is submitting, but there's no error. The file just goes away. When I plug my phone into the safari dev tools on my mac, the file field is populated with the value of the file when I choose it, but then as soon as I hit submit the field gets cleared to `""` and all I see on the network tab is two blank `about:blank` responses one of type js, one of type other

Below is my form itself. There is no `Post` request showing up in my logs, so I don't think it can possibly be anything from the controller or elsewhere. Lastly, I tried using Chrome's mobile inspect tool Chrome:://inspect and there were no javascript errors that showed up as far as I could see.

If anyone has any ideas of where I can go next on this debugging journey, I'd really appreciate the help.

```
<%= simple_form_for current_user.profile, url: profiles_photo_step_path, method: :post, remote: true do |f| %>
  <div class="carrierwave-button-div">
    <%= f.input :image, as: :file, label: false %>
   </div>       
   <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-default", data: {disable_with: "Submitting..."}  %>
   <div class="primary-center-text" style="margin-top: 15px; padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px;">
     <a href="#sign-up-complete" class="skip-step-link blue-link" id="skip-photo-link">Skip for now</a>
   </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Could it be tied to `:onchange => "readURL(this)"`? Can you please add the definition of that function?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've simply removed that `:onchange` attribute and it has made no difference (it's there so it can show an image preview, but I removed all the extra bells and whistles and it still behaved the same way.

Comment: The only thing I've tried that has made it work, is removing the `remote: :true`, but based on the step by step process it is part of, it needs to be submitted with ajax. And again, `remote: true` works fine in a desktop browser.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I feel dumb for not trying this sooner once I isolated that `remote: true` was the problem, but I'll post my solution just in case anyone has this very specific issue in the future.

I was using `gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.2'` as per the [gem documentation](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart). I upgraded to `remotipart 1.4.4` and the form submitted the file.